# What is the difference between "evaluate" and "return $!"?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, evaluation, io-monad

Here's an extract from the documentation of `evaluate`:

```
Control.Exception.Base.evaluate :: a -> IO a
```

> ```
> evaluate x
> ```
>
> is not the same as
>
> ```
> return $! x
> ```
>
> A correct definition is
>
> ```
> evaluate x = (return $! x) >>= return
> ```

([source](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate))

These seem to have the same meaning. What is the difference between these two definitions?

Comment: Doesn't this actually violate the monad laws?

Comment: @leftaroundabout No, it doesn't. Both behave exactly the same if run, but if you `seq` the expressions, `return $! x` has a `seq` outermost, while `(return $! x) >>= return` has a `(>>=)` outermost.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: No, because ⊥ is ignored for the purposes of laws. Standard monads like `Reader` behave the same way. (I don't buy Daniel Fischer's argument (which I've heard before from others), because "behave exactly the same if run" isn't really a well-defined concept.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure whether your statement is correct. `\`seq\`` has lower precedence than `>>=` - how can `>>=` be outermost?

Comment: @mucaho I was speaking of the two expressions that would become the argument of `seq`. In `seq (return $! x)`, the `return $! x` has a `seq` [from `$!`] outermost, while in `seq ((return $! x) >>= return)`, the `(return $! x) >>= return` has a `>>=` outermost.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Quick ref:

The type of `evaluate` is:

```
evaluate :: a -> IO a
```

`seq` has the type `a -> b -> b`. It firstly evaluates the first argument, then returns the second argument.

Evaluate follows these three rules:

```
evaluate x `seq` y    ==>  y
evaluate x `catch` f  ==>  (return $! x) `catch` f
evaluate x >>= f      ==>  (return $! x) >>= f
```

---

The difference between the `return $! x` and `(return $! x) >>= return` becomes apparent with this expression:

```
evaluate undefined `seq` 42
```

By the first rule, that must evaluate to 42.

With the `return $! x` definition, the above expression would cause an undefined exception. This has the value ⊥, which doesn't equal 42.

With the `(return $! x) >>= return` definition, it does equal 42.

Basically, the `return $! x` form is strict when the IO value is calculated. The other form is only strict when the IO value is run and the value used (using `>>=`).

See [this mailing list thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/6867) for more details.

Comment: Why is `(return $! undefined) >>= return` different from `return $! undefined`? My guess is the former introduces one additional layer of indirection which prevents `undefined` from being evaluated in `((return $! undefined) >>= return) \`seq\` 42`.